# Phalcon - Model Resultset Simple query twice

Tags: model, resultset, phalcon

I found that when i call

```
Hierarchy::addFirstNodeBelowOfId(1);
```

in controller just once. The result is that the model call stored routine named

```
hierarchy_addFirstNodeBelowOfId();
```

twice.

```
class Hierarchy extends Model{
.
.
.
public static function addFirstNodeBelowOfId($nodeId, $newNodeName = 'new node'){
    $sql = "call `hierarchy_addFirstNodeBelowOfId`($nodeId, '$newNodeName');";
    $model = new Hierarchy();
    $results = new Resultset(null, $model, $model->getWriteConnection()->query($sql)); 
    return $results;
}
}
```

Does anyone know why Model do like that? or I did something wrong.
please suggest.

Comment: Try without last line `return $results;` or make it like `return $results = new Resultset(null, $model, $model->getWriteConnection()->query($sql));`.

Comment: Tried. the result is the same... twice.

Comment: Also tried ->execute($sql)); instead of ->query($sql)); but the result is the same. - twice...

Comment: Also tried just $model->getWriteConnection()->execute($sql); instead of new Resultset(...); but the result is the same. - twice

Comment: Is there something in constructor maybe?

Comment: no onConstruct() function exist. just $this->setSource(); in initialize() function.

Comment: Are you sure you are not using `addFirstNodeBelowOfId` inside model? Eg. in validators or `afterFetch`-like methods?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found that there are extra request to /favicon.ico where favicon.ico does not exist then it redirect to my default homepage so it seem that i request to my default homepage twice.

```
[Tue, 22 Sep 15 11:11:41 +0700][DEBUG] $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : /
[Tue, 22 Sep 15 11:11:41 +0700][DEBUG] $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : /favicon.ico
```

Solved by add favicon.ico into /public/ folder.

Comment: So a visit makes you adding new node? I would assume this is still a bug.